# Documents and settings access denied

Tags: windows, directory-structure

I cant create "Documents and settings" folder in C:\ or see it even if i enable "show hidden folders".

I have a lot of custom built applications which use the path"C:\Documents and settings..." but since i moved from xp to w7 this folder has changed name. And all these applications fail because the path is not accessible. Is there a solution or do i have to change all references of the path in all my applications?

Comment: Ignore this comment. Sorry all for confusion but stackoverflow didnt let me submit my original question so i removed all the info then edited it to put the info back. silly silly

Comment: It doesn't exist on Win7. You should fix your applications so they use the proper folder locations, as it doesn't exist on Win8 either, and XP is EOL as of April. There are dozens of posts here on SO about where the proper location is to store files, both for your app and for users of your app, that can give you the details based on the language you're coding in.

Comment: If it doesnt exist why is it that when i try to create it i get the message "this destination already contains a folder named 'Documents and Settings'

Comment: Windows 7 tries to map Documents and Settings to `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents` using a junction. (Use `dir /ah` from a command prompt open on `C:\`.) It does not actually contain that folder. But that doesn't matter; the fact is that that folder does not exist on Win7, and it's the wrong place to be trying to store data.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I have just managed to create the folder on another pc running win7. Now i am very confused. Any clue to why it will work on one but not the other?!?!?!?!

Comment: No, and it really doesn't matter. :-) *Fix your code to work properly*. MS has been providing information on the proper places to store data (and API calls to locate them) since XP was released more than a decade ago. You've had plenty of time to correct things before, and it's highly unlikely those changes will be undone in the future, so bite the bullet and make the necessary corrections. :-)